# Ruby on Rails features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber

I am trying to write a feature for clicking a button my query runs like Select * from histories where name %LIKE% (data) and show it is page.

I have written so far:

Scenario: Specific Records

```
When I fill in "search" with "Akshay"

And I press "Search"

Then I should see records of Akshay
```

Can somebody help me to write the web definitions for the the third line "Then Then I should see records of Akshay"

Thank you

Comment: You probably want to use `expect(page).to have_content` or use `expect(page).to have_selector`.

Answer (score 0):

In the step you can write like below

```
Then /^I should see records of following people$/ do |data|
 records = page.all("#records")
 data.hashes.each do |row|
  record = records.find do |record|
    record.text =~ Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(row["name"]))
  end
  raise "record not found." if record.blank?
end
```

Similary then in the scenario u can write

```
Then I should see records of following people
|name |
|Aksay|
```